# Ubuntu 18.04, gdm3, X11 an fixed frame rate

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kvm-switch, framerate, gdm

I'm using ubuntu 18.04.02 with 2 displays. 
The Graphic adapter is connected using DP to an KVM switch, which is connected to an 4K  display (called Display 1), which supports only 30hz frame rate.

During startup, ubuntu will detect/activate 60hz frame / refresh rate for display 1, which is not supported by the display.

So how can I set the frame rate -system wide- to 30hz?

What I did:

I set up 30 hz at the `~/.config/monitors.xml`. But the `monitors.xml` is applied after the gdm3 login. But I can't login, because the login page is provided with 60hz, which results in an blank display.

Searching the web I found some information to change the rate by editing the `xorg.conf` file, which does net exist in ubuntu 18.04.

Any idea, how I can set frame rate persistent to 30 hz on display 1?

Answer (score 0):

I just was struggling with something very similar to this and finally found a fix.

My particular issue was caused by using the proprietary nvidia drivers with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I am hooking up an older VGA monitor (Rosewill R912E, 1280x1024 native res) which improperly reports EDID info.  The nvidia drivers try to run at 85 hz and the monitor pops up an annoying "Input Not Supported" box on the screen.  Manually setting the display frequency to 75 Hz fixes the problem once logged in, but for the GDM3 login screen, I still get was getting this annoying "Input Not Supported" box.

Here is what I did to fix the problem:

Editing /etc/X11/xorg.conf:

Found this section:

```
Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Toshiba Matsushita Display Technology Co., Ltd R912E"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 95.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 85.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

Changed VertRefresh from "55.0 - 85.0" to "55.0 - 75.0" to force the refresh rate to stay at 75 or lower.

And in this section:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1280x1024_75 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I added a line:

```
Option         "UseEdidFreqs" "false"
```

The metamodes line may also be useful, but will get automatically added by the nvidia-settings tool which is installed by default on Ubuntu.

Source: http://http.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/1.0-9626/README/appendix-d.html